# Rotate results with SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sum, unpivot

I'm using [Blazer](https://github.com/ankane/blazer) have the following query:

```
SELECT 
sum(active_paid_users_count) as Active,
sum(inactive_paid_users_count) as Inactive,
sum(free_users_count) as Free
FROM accounts
WHERE
  trialing = false
  AND
  cancelled = false
```

This produces the following table:

[image: sql results]

I'd like to rotate this table so that I can get a pie chart result out of [Blazer](https://blazer.dokkuapp.com/queries/17-pie-chart). It would end up looking like this:

```
Type     Count
active      31
inactive    76
free       190
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unpivot with a a lateral join. The upside is that this requires a single table scan:

```
select v.type, v.cnt
from (
    select 
        sum(active_paid_users_count) as active,
        sum(inactive_paid_users_count) as inactive,
        sum(free_users_count) as free
    from accounts
    where trialing = false and cancelled = false
) t
cross join lateral (
    values ('active', t.active), ('inactive', t.inactive), ('free', t.free)
) as v(type, cnt)
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of unions should take of this for you.

```
SELECT 'Active'                     AS Type, 
     , sum(active_paid_users_count) AS Count
FROM accounts
WHERE
  trialing = false
  AND
  cancelled = false

UNION

SELECT 'Inactive'                     AS Type, 
     , sum(inactive_paid_users_count) AS Count
FROM accounts
WHERE
  trialing = false
  AND
  cancelled = false

UNION

SELECT 'Free'                AS Type, 
     , sum(free_users_count) AS Count
FROM accounts
WHERE
  trialing = false
  AND
  cancelled = false
```